# Add alias to installed rpm

Tags: mysql, linux, rpm

First a small situation sketch. We have CentOS 7 and we want to install the opensource version of Oreka (http://oreka.sourceforge.net/). However the software hasn't received updates since 2013.

So we found that in the install script it looks for the rpm package mysql-server. But rpm -q returns package not found since the name is mysql-community-server now. So the question is can we add the alias "mysql-server" somehow to "mysql-community-server" to fool the script. This would be more convenient than rebuilding the install script/package.

Comment: No, you can't add an alias without rebuilding the `mysql-server` RPM. It might be easier to modify the script to look for `mysql-community-server`.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your own empty RPM that "`Provides`" `mysql-server` and "`Requires`" `mysql-community-server` to do this kind of aliasing. You can call it something like `mysql-server-compat-myorg`.